# Anyway to search inside a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

We use to be able to use agent ransack to search all our crystal reports (.rpt files) for the use of a stored procedure. That was when we had Crystal 8.5. We now have Crystal 2008 and it doesn't seem to work anymore (change of format in rpt files?). Anyone know a utility that would be able do do this?

Comment: found something called rpt inspector but we are not willing to spend $300+ just to search crystal.

Comment: At one point, I used to be able to search .RPT files (using 'A word or phrase in the file' option) with Windows Explorer (F3).  For some reason, this isn't working in Windows XP.  Perhaps I had the content index enabled on my Windows 2000 (long gone) workstation.

Comment: @user127954, craig has just raised what I think may be the key: in Microsoft operating systems from XP onwards, system utilities (such as search) no longer access files that have applications associated with their file extensions (such as .rpt with Crystal Reports). Essentially, Microsoft have deliberately crippled their own operating system. A way to check would be to rename a specific report (which you know accesses a particular procedure) to an unassociated file extension (such as .rpx, probably) and then use your old tool (agent ransack) to search the renamed file for the known procedure.

Comment: @MarkBannister This shouldn't be the case for Agent Ransack, though. I just gave it a shot and it did search the .rpt files and even gave a few hits, but failed to find everything. Looks like it is just matching on the comments inside the reports. It worked on a couple of my very old (~2000) reports, though, so that would suggest it is due to CR changing the file format in newer versions.

Comment: @Ryan put your comment as a answer and i will mark it complete. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good comparison of commercial .rpt management utilities here: [kenhamady.com/reportmanagementutilities.pdf](http://kenhamady.com/reportmanagementutilities.pdf). However, these are mostly... "not very good", let's say, and very expensive (not to mention some don't work with CR2008). I'd suggest getting a hold of some demo versions first to see if they'll work for your needs.